# how can i keep comma in the price and also calculate the price

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

1)I am developing a ecommerce site , in that my price is  $190000 but i want to that price as $ 1,90,000 (with commas) how to show like that

2)Dollar value is changing all the time how can i calculate the price of the item

Comment: what kind of currency format is `$1,90,000` ?

Comment: it is in US dollars only, just if we keep the commas it is easily undestandable

Comment: I think the average user would expect `$1,90` for one dollar ninety cent or `$190,000.00` for hundredninetythousand, but `$1,90,000` looks like a misspelling where the user needs to guess do they mean `1,90` or `90000` or even something else. For sure I would close the browsertab if I see a commerce site with prices that look invalid.

Comment: See this example http://demo.shop-script.com/free/index.php. And give me the solution

Comment: Your demo page shows prices like `$1,90` which is a normal currency format. See the answers below how to do that with `PHP`. For your second part of the question: I only can guess that you actually want to use another currency than dollars. Just multiply/divide with the exchange rate and you will get the price in another currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP one function is there to format the price.

```
number_format()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Can u give me answer for the second question also

Comment: Here you have use money_format() function. May be it will help : http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0):

Use php function which is as below.

```
number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

for more detail regarding this function google it on php.net

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but in c# you can use string format. That would do the trick in the .net world